# Did time run backwards in the 1890s? How to explain surprising graph of DateTime.ToOADate for negative values?

Tags: .net, datetime

The function [DateTime.ToOADate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netframework-4.7) maps DateTime values to numbers.

Can the function below be simplified?

```
// drop time component
double DateComponent(double date) => DateTime.FromOADate(date).Date.ToOADate();
```

Is it not equivalent to Math.Floor? I reasoned. However, when I tested thoroughly (with FsCheck), I found it gives different results for negative values:

```
 > DateComponent(-4.1)
 -4
 > Math.Floor(-4.1)
 -5
```

It seems DateComponent rounds towards zero, rather than down.

To understand better, I plotted a graph of DateTime.ToOADate. For positive values, the line is straight and increasing with time. However for negative values, the graph is piecewise decreasing with left-discontinuities at integer values. What's going on?

1. Why is the graph like that? Is this a bug? If by design, why? Time didn't run backwards in the 1890s. The function ToOADate violates many reasonable assumptions

   - f is increasing with time, ie. t1 < t2 implies f(t1) < f(t2)
   - f is continuous
2. Can the DateComponent function be simplified to pure arithmetic?

[image: graph of DateTime.ToOADate]

Comment: Use `Math.Truncate`? (or simply cast to `long`).

Comment: No bug, since this is used in almost every computer since the 90s. OADate isn't a Unix timestamp. The integral part is a day offset. The fractional part is a time *multiplier*. In any case trying to use math operations on *dates* can result in a lot of funny and unexpected results, simply because you *cant* treat Dates or time as an offset from a single point. There are timezones changes, calendar changes (a *lot* of countries switched to the Gregorian calendar after 1900), leap seconds etc to account for. The US Olympic team almost lost the first Olympics because of the calendar differences

Comment: If you care about accurate times and calculations 100 years in the past you'll have to use the IANA timezone database. In some cases it *does* contain rules for the 19th century, eg for Russia

Comment: A value like -4.0 maps to 12AM on December 26th.  -4.1 logically maps to the previous day.  But doesn't, it behaves like -4.0 + 0.1.  This goes back to the first version of Excel, they had to duplicate the bugs in Lotus 123 to be competitive.  Another famous 123 bug is that it treated 1900 as a leap year.  Don't use OADate to map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of [OLE automation date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx) is "funny":

> An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899, and whose fractional component represents the time on that day divided by 24. For example, midnight, 31 December 1899 is represented by 1.0; 6 A.M., 1 January 1900 is represented by 2.25; midnight, 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.0; and 6 A.M., 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.25.

So it isn't a simple distance between 0 and the OLE date. In truth it is a date (the integer part) "encoded" together with a time (the fractional part). This generates an interesting paradox:

```
DateTime.FromOADate(0.1) == DateTime.FromOADate(-0.1)
```

In both cases the integer part is `0` and the fractional part is `0.1` :-) (in both cases it *1899-12-30 02:24:00*)

Now... You can simply use `Math.Truncate` or cast to `long` to truncate the values.

```
static double DateComponent(double date) => Math.Truncate(date);

static double DateComponent(double date) => (long)date;
```

More authoritative [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82ab7w69.aspx) explaining the format of OLE dates, where they give the example with 0.75/-0.75 .

Answer (score 0):

Reading the .NET reference source, the implementations of ToOADate and FromOADate special case negative values.

https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/3b1eaf5203992df69de44c783a3eda37d3d4cd10/mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#L548

```
// Converts an OLE Date to a tick count.
// This function is duplicated in COMDateTime.cpp
internal static long DoubleDateToTicks(double value) {
    // The check done this way will take care of NaN
    if (!(value < OADateMaxAsDouble) || !(value > OADateMinAsDouble))
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_OleAutDateInvalid"));

    // Conversion to long will not cause an overflow here, as at this point the "value" is in between OADateMinAsDouble and OADateMaxAsDouble
    long millis = (long)(value * MillisPerDay + (value >= 0? 0.5: -0.5));
    // The interesting thing here is when you have a value like 12.5 it all positive 12 days and 12 hours from 01/01/1899
    // However if you a value of -12.25 it is minus 12 days but still positive 6 hours, almost as though you meant -11.75 all negative
    // This line below fixes up the millis in the negative case
    if (millis < 0) {
        millis -= (millis % MillisPerDay) * 2;
    }

    millis += DoubleDateOffset / TicksPerMillisecond;

    if (millis < 0 || millis >= MaxMillis) throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_OleAutDateScale"));
    return millis * TicksPerMillisecond;
}
```